# Display 500 and error instead of 502 on nginx with fpm upstream

Tags: php, nginx

i will start off with my setup is running nicely for all requests that are intended to send <400 status codes.

On my dev environment i do want to send the actual 500 error to the client including the error.
nginx does not pass that along, but logs the error and displays its built-in 502 page.

i tried setting `fastcgi_intercept_errors off;`, although this is the default, but that did not work either.

The nginx in question is 1.15.3 from the official docker container.

the config is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name localhost;

    error_log  /dev/stdout;
    access_log /dev/stdout;

    root /var/www/html/app/public;

    gzip on;

    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;


location / {
try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}


    location ~ \.php$ {

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 1000;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
    }

}
```

i'd be happy witrh any suggestions.

best regards

*update*

It turns out that a simple exception does not respond with a 500 when display_errors is turned on (which is the dev case).

I fixed this with middleware.

Comment: What generates the 500 error? Is it the `index.php` script? I just tested `http_response_code(500);` and it passes through to the client with no problem.

Comment: i added an exception to a controller to test this issue.

Comment: There are probably more config files you haven't shown, eg the main `nginx.conf`, what do they look like?  Also `conf.d/default.conf` usually includes something like `error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;`, is that in play?

Comment: @RichardSmith your comment let me to check, if i actually generate a 500 with an exception, thus leading to my answer (see update). so thank you!